# Datapower timeout is in what unit?

Tags: ibm-datapower

Can someone please let me know if the timeout we set is in seconds or milli seconds.  In setting it is no where mention.

By default it is 120 but with no units even if i click where IBM gives explanation is not having the unit mentioned there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timeout is in seconds.

In general, you are much better off using the documentation at the IBM Knowledge Center instead of relying on the WebGui help.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/